# How to get GUI label to display all integers between a given start and end value?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, label, jlabel

This is an image on which everything relevant is visible (also pasted code below):

```
http://i.imgur.com/PZY7rRe.png
```

I didnt actually put the if loop in yet, but I will.

Anyway, the problem is, I can't get the red text to display all the integers in between the two values like it appears in the console. I realize that this is because its just outputting the ending value, since the program keeps refreshing until the end of the loop, so fast that it just looks like its returning the inputted end value in the label. (I think)

So how do I manage to make the red text (this.lblOutput.setText();) display all the integers and not replace itself until the end? I considered trying to get the console output as a string and just setting the lblOutput text as that string, but then I realized that I don't know how to do that either :(

Thank you for your time and patience.

```
//Obtain starting value from string input        
String startInput = this.txtInput_start.getText();
int startValue = Integer.parseInt(startInput);

//Obtain ending value from string input
String endInput = this.txtInput_end.getText();
int endValue = Integer.parseInt(endInput);

//Construct loop to display all integers between and inclusive of the two input values
//Put an if statement so that it wont loop error if end is smaller than start   

for (int i = startValue; i<=endValue; i++){

    System.out.println(i);
    //above was just to demonstrate how console prints all ints but lblOutput does not.
    this.lblOutput.setText(String.valueOf(i));

}               
}
```

Comment: WTF man! Just copy the code and the output. If nothing else at least adjust the size. It's humongous.

Comment: Do you to display ALL the values (1..10), only one value at a time with some delay between them??

Comment: Beware of linking content to questions, a lot of people won't follow the links and some can't see them due to firewall issues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is showing only the last value because every time you enter the loop, you erase the content of the label, so here is what I think you want:

```
for (int i = startValue; i<=endValue; i++){
    System.out.println(i);
    //above was just to demonstrate how console prints all ints but lblOutput does not.
    this.lblOutput.setText(this.lblOutput.getText() + " " + String.valueOf(i));

}
```

Comment: A `StringBuilder` and setting the value at the end of the loop would be more efficient, as you are not creating a bunch of temporary `String`s and the UI won't update until you exit the `actionPerformed` method anyway.

Comment: Indeed MadProgrammer, this is just the simplest way to do it without any optimization

Comment: You have a chance to educate, best practices make perfect ;)

Comment: It worked, and I am sincerely thankful for that. However, this leads to another question - why did this work? Is it because everytime it iterated, it saved the last integer, and is displaying it again?

Comment: It works because the last displayed text is read then the current integer is added, then we put them together and display them